# How to instantiate Flysystem adapter dynamically?

Tags: php, symfony, flysystem

I'm using Symfony 6 and Flysystem 3, and depending on a parameter I want to pick one of the 2 adapters I have.

I don't want to instantiate both of them in the constructor since I'm only using 1 per execution (it's a Consumer).

Tried to instantiate the Container and use $container->get('my.adapter'):

```
public function __construct(
        private readonly ContainerInterface $container
    ) {
    }
```

However I'm missing something:

> Cannot autowire service "App\Consumer\MyConsumer": argument
> "$container" of method "__construct()" references interface
> "Symfony\Component\DependencyInjection\ContainerInte     rface" but no
> such service exists. You should maybe alias this interface to the
> existing "service_container" service.

Any ideas??

Comment: you might look into using the [mount manager](https://flysystem.thephpleague.com/docs/advanced/mount-manager/)

Comment: Think I jumped that in the documentation, thanks for letting me know, looking into that, it seems promissing!